# What is the reason that CNN classify some images horribly wrong

Tags: tensorflow, cnn, mnist

I'm trying to train a CNN for MNIST, everything goes well except for the loss stays very high in my model, while it's very low in example(which has different structure).

**this model still yields high accuracy though there is high loss.**

Here I attached my code.

```
with tf.name_scope("inputs"):
    X = inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, 
                                shape=[None, 28, 28, 1], name="X")
    y = tf.placeholder(
                    tf.int32,
                    name="y")

    training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, [], name="training")

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
                        inputs,
                        filters=6,
                        kernel_size=3,
                        strides=(1, 1),
                        padding='SAME',
                        activation=tf.nn.selu,
                        name="conv1",
                    )

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
                        conv1,
                        filters=12,
                        kernel_size=3,
                        strides=(1, 1),
                        padding='SAME',
                        activation=tf.nn.selu,
                        name="conv2",
                    )

max_pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
                            conv2,
                            pool_size=8,
                            strides=2,
                            padding='SAME',
                            name="max_pool3"
                        )
with tf.name_scope("conv4"):
    conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(
                            max_pool3,
                            filters=12,
                            kernel_size=3,
                            strides=(1, 1),
                            padding='SAME',
                            activation=tf.nn.selu,
                            name="conv4",
                        )

    num_ele = int(conv4.shape[1]*conv4.shape[2]*conv4.shape[3])
    conv4_flat = tf.reshape(
                        conv4,
                        shape=[-1, num_ele],
                        name="conv4_flat"
                      )
    conv4_flat_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(conv4_flat, rate=dropout_rate,
                                        training=training,
                                        name="conv4_flat_dropout")

with tf.name_scope("fc5"):
    fc5 = tf.layers.dense(
                            conv4_flat_dropout,
                            conv4_flat_dropout.shape[1]//2,
                            activation=tf.nn.selu,
                            name="fc5",
                        )
    fc5_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(fc5, rate=dropout_rate,
                                   training=training,
                                   name="fc5_dropout")

logits = tf.layers.dense(
                        fc5_dropout,
                        n_outputs,
                        name="logits",
                    )
```

And the training process

```
# It starts with very low accuracy, but instead in the sample after the first epoch the accuracy for training sets reaches 1.
 0 train loss:1.8484
    train acc:0.751745
                     validation loss:1.7019
                      validation acc:0.7656
 1 train loss:0.0745
    train acc:0.978927
                     validation loss:0.0782
                      validation acc:0.9764
 2 train loss:0.0958
    train acc:0.972818
                     validation loss:0.1072
                      validation acc:0.9706
 3 train loss:0.1186
    train acc:0.971727
                     validation loss:0.1292
                      validation acc:0.9714
 4 train loss:0.1397
    train acc:0.969836
                     validation loss:0.1422
                     validation acc:0.9738
# Accuracy for some reason always drops dramaticlt here. Which I don't understand why.
 5 train loss:0.8394
    train acc:0.939564
                     validation loss:0.8237
                      validation acc:0.9470
 6 train loss:0.3108
    train acc:0.979182
                     validation loss:0.3345
                      validation acc:0.9786
 7 train loss:0.6576
    train acc:0.967382
                     validation loss:0.8300
                      validation acc:0.9652
 8 train loss:0.2005
    train acc:0.987273
                     validation loss:0.3021
                      validation acc:0.9832
 9 train loss:0.2915
    train acc:0.984145
                     validation loss:0.4509
                      validation acc:0.9812
10 train loss:0.7932
    train acc:0.968273
                     validation loss:1.1119
                      validation acc:0.9634
11 train loss:0.2778
    train acc:0.988636
                     validation loss:0.4988
                      validation acc:0.9848
12 train loss:0.4892
    train acc:0.982982
                     validation loss:0.6407
                      validation acc:0.9826
13 train loss:0.5457
    train acc:0.983382
                     validation loss:0.9361
                      validation acc:0.9806
14 train loss:0.3998
    train acc:0.989527
                     validation loss:0.7423
                      validation acc:0.9876
15 train loss:0.3925
    train acc:0.985745
                     validation loss:0.7599
                      validation acc:0.9788
16 train loss:0.2093
    train acc:0.993236
                     validation loss:0.5771
                      validation acc:0.9850
17 train loss:0.5663
    train acc:0.989855
                     validation loss:1.2298
                      validation acc:0.9846
18 train loss:0.6623
    train acc:0.988927
                     validation loss:1.3572
                      validation acc:0.9824
19 train loss:0.1555
    train acc:0.994891
                     validation loss:0.6606
                      validation acc:0.9872
```

And the sample code.

```
with tf.name_scope("inputs"):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_inputs], name="X")
    X_reshaped = tf.reshape(X, shape=[-1, height, width, channels])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="y")
    training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=[], name='training')

conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X_reshaped, filters=conv1_fmaps, kernel_size=conv1_ksize,
                     strides=conv1_stride, padding=conv1_pad,
                     activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv1")
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, filters=conv2_fmaps, kernel_size=conv2_ksize,
                     strides=conv2_stride, padding=conv2_pad,
                     activation=tf.nn.relu, name="conv2")

with tf.name_scope("pool3"):
    pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID")
    pool3_flat = tf.reshape(pool3, shape=[-1, pool3_fmaps * 14 * 14])
    pool3_flat_drop = tf.layers.dropout(pool3_flat, conv2_dropout_rate, training=training)

with tf.name_scope("fc1"):
    fc1 = tf.layers.dense(pool3_flat_drop, n_fc1, activation=tf.nn.relu, name="fc1")
    fc1_drop = tf.layers.dropout(fc1, fc1_dropout_rate, training=training)

with tf.name_scope("output"):
    logits = tf.layers.dense(fc1, n_outputs, name="output")
    Y_proba = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="Y_proba")
```

I found that most of the classifications are classified with very high probability(like 1). Both those correct ones and false ones.


(softmax probablity)
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.966008e-33 0.000000e+00]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]

[image: ![Image of classes]()]
The probability are corresponidng to each of the images

My question is

Why will this happen what exactly caused this, was it a bug in my code or it's natural for this to happen?

If this has to do with the architecture, what potential problem might cause it and how can I fix this problem and avoid this in the future?

Why is the accuracy after first epoch so low and why the accuracy drops a lot after 3 to 6 epoches?

Was the styling of my code acceptable, and what should I improve?

Original codes are here

 
https://github.com/Dovermore/handson-ml/blob/master/chapter_13_exer/question_7.ipynb
https://github.com/Dovermore/handson-ml/blob/master/13_convolutional_neural_networks.ipynb
(go to the bottom to find the related segment in the second link)

Comment: maybe you should train more and use better hyper-parameters, like drop parameter, for avoiding over-fitting. Even you may change the entire architecture for performing better. I recommend you putting your code snippets here.

Comment: My machine is pretty slow in training CNN, I'm still studying relative topic, should I try tuning parameters? I want to progress more and spend more time on some more complex things later.

Comment: If it is slow, take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/24319/28175). You should tune your parameters first. If your model is unable to learn, then you can change the hyper parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember classification is computational process with group of numbers in matrices and when you train a model for particular set it goes through the data and build a matrices that is called as trained model.

When you give a data set to classify, It tries to associate the values of test data with trained models and it just classifies mathematically,If any labels in the model comes close to that of test data it tries to associate that test data to the highest accurate that it identifies not true output but predicted mathematically

Sometimes they may fall into into the wrong label based on the accuracy of your model and when your training a data like MNIST,sometimes it does classify to wrong labels when parameters are not tuned as such its accuracy is low

Hope it helps

Comment: But I went through all the test probabilities, and almost all of the predictions are very close to one, or with only two possible class, and all other classes have a probability of zero. There are 50000 training instances and 10000 test instances, it's not realistic every single MNIST test case is close to training cases. And it doesn't seems like overfitting either, since the training accuracy stays around 99% while the validation stays around 98%. Was it normal for these above things to happen? I haven't tuned hyperparameter yet, because it's taking too much time to tun one training session

Comment: Start by tunnng parameters and to decrease loss try spliting train and test in different sizes